# Video playback on IOS11 doesnt work (construct2 / cordova)

Tags: cordova, video, ios11, construct-2

I got a question about a project i released months ago. I included video files (intro) which worked perfektly. But now our customer told us that on ios 11 the video plackback isnt working anymore. I tried it out and hes right. I can only hear the audio, but the video doesnt shows up. The app is exported with cordova and was "crossplatformed" with the intel XDK

Is this a problem, i would have to fix? Or is it may a problem apple will fix with a newer update. Has someone an identical experience?

Note: On the preview version (ios 10.xx.xx) everything works...so iam not sure about how to handle this problem. I told, that its primary an ios problem. Basically there are no more techniques you can include a video file into the project. I didnt used some plugins or anything else, so it should be a common issue.

Thanks in advance for a feedback!

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video or even an output from ffprobe so we can see the details of the video? From your description it does sound like an iOS issue but that may not help you if it is not fixed quickly

Comment: Hello Mick!
First things first: Thanks for your help! :) 

Link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d02a0ca652dad95602d8acf39e86ad4c20170926153106/5c76af

ive a link (WeTransfer - i hope its okay) with a test video file (its not the original, but with the exact same codec and specifications). We also tried different codec specs like h.265 but the result is always the same. I think its an ios 11 problem... because the video playback doesnt work on devices with this version. But hopefully you can give me a hint how to handle this, because apple could not help... Thank you vermy much!

Answer (score 0):

The output from ffprobe for the video you linked to looks like it should play as you say:

```js
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/testvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-09-26T14:58:09.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:06.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 524 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-09-26T14:58:09.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
```

Given it did play previously the long term solution is likely to be the proper iOS fix, but in the shorter term if you were to re-encode it using 'baseline' rather than 'high' h.264 profile you may find it has a better chance of working.

Most devices try to make sure they at least support properly baseline encodings so you will often find it used when targeting mobile devices. Its not as efficient for a given quality but that may be an ok trade-off temporarily for you at this time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an iOS 11 device that I could check your video  with, but there are definitely others who are seeing iOS 11 video problems: e.g: https://community.box.com/t5/Mobile-Troubleshooting/Streaming-Video-Does-Not-Work-in-iOS-11/ta-p/43614, https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/274672/plex-video-playback-broken-in-ios-11/p10

Comment: Hey Mick! Thank you for your input! So would you agree, when i would say, that its an ios update "issue" and may will be fixed by apple? I tried it with baseline codec, but its the same result - ios 10 and lower: no problem. IOS 11...........nothing.............i love you apple...basically i was wondering if iam the only person on earth who has this problem :) because i cannot find any other report. Please note: if iam opening the video on the ipad directly (device player - it works)

Comment: @IDK A quick update - there seems to be increasing reports of this issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8082640?start=30&tstart=0. If you did/do find it was specific to your video can you include an update here?